# how to get confirm that a shared user are inivited by member of website?

Tags: social-sharing

If I install a social plugin to invite users per Facebook or Google+ – how do I know that a user have invited some of user and that user are has become member through that link?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin pie register http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pie-register/
Here you can enable invitation codes and require invitation code to register.

Another plugin that allows tracking invitation codes is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/baw-invitation-codes/